# Create "bare" pgp private key / Make private key without being able to generate the public key from it

Tags: pgp, key-generation, asymmetric, openpgp, public-key

How do you create a private-key/public-key pair without the public key's information in the private key? So you should basically not be able to extract the public key from the private key. The private key should contain the bare minimum.

If yes, is this possible in Javascript using `openpgp`?

Comment: Are you looking to just omit the public key packets from being written, or to not be able to generate the public key at all?  The latter is impossible, since it's always possible to generate the public key from the data in an OpenPGP private key packet.

Comment: Is this similar to what you had in mind? https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31670/44503

Comment: @bk2204 If you're not able to generate the public key, by not writing the public key packets into the private key, then yes, I want to omit these packets. So basically the private key should only contain the absolute necessary parts required for it to work.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem.  Regardless of whether the public key packets are written to the private key file, the public key can easily be calculated from the private key (see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45151/anatomy-of-an-rsa-private-key/78460#78460).  What is the underlying problem that you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @mti2935 that's actually a bummer. I'm creating a system where both the public key and private key needs to be kept secret and only the two parties involved have access to their pair. The keys are used to create kind of write-only and read-only pairs.

I guess I'll stick to create two pairs and then sign the data with the private key A and after that encrypt it with the public key B.

Comment: OK, that makes much more sense now.  It sounds like what you might be looking for is 'key exchange', where A shares his public key with B, and B shares his public key with A, - then they both end up with a shared secret which both A and B know, but nobody else knows.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman for more info.  http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/ecdh.html is also instructive.